# Difference between display none and display block

Tags: html, css, styling

What is the difference between setting a control's style `display: none` and `display: block`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The display property defines how a certain HTML element should be displayed. Display `block` and `none` are used to show or hide html elements. You can read more about display property and available options **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)**.

- none: The element will not be displayed at all.
- block: The element displayed as a block-level element (like paragraphs and headers)

Comment: Newbies can interpret "block" as display will be blocked and you can't see it :)

Comment: @Thyag But you CAN see an element with display: block, so what you're saying makes zero sense.

Answer (score 13):

**Display:none;** - The element is in the `DOM` but is NOT visible and does not take up any `space` unlike `visibility:hidden`.

**Display: block;** - A block element takes up the `full width` available and does not allow other elements to be placed beside them. Example: `div`

Answer (score 3):

These two style properties do two different things.

**display: none** removes the element completely from the document. It does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in the source code. (The element will generate no box at all)

**display: block** the element will span the full width of the space available to it. (a line break before and after the element)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a CSS property i think. This is used to show/hide DOM elements

CSS property is display and the value is 'none', 'block', etc

Referring from : **[CSS Display](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/display)** as suggested by http://w3fools.com/

**block**

***Object is rendered as a block element.***

**none**

***Element is not rendered. The element (it has no effect on layout); all child elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element did not exist.***

**inline**

Default. Object is rendered as an inline element sized by the dimensions of the content.

**list-item**

Internet Explorer 6 and later. Object is rendered as a block element, and a list-item marker is added.

**table-header-group**

Object is rendered as tHead. Table header is always displayed before all other rows and row groups, and after any top captions. The header is displayed on each document spanned by a table.

**table-footer-group**

Object is rendered as tFoot. Table footer is always displayed after all other rows and row groups, and before any bottom captions. The footer is displayed on each document spanned by a table.

**inline-block**

Object is rendered inline, but the contents of the object are rendered as a block element. Adjacent inline elements are rendered on the same line, space permitting.

Answer (score 1):

`Display:none;` means the element will not be displayed, and `Display:block;` means the element is displayed as a block-level element (like paragraphs and headers).

Answer (score 1):

There is another nuance to display:none; if you dynamically insert a div as a child to a parent div--***and you explicitly set the visibility property of the child*** to "visible", the visibility property of the parent will only make the parent visible/invisible; the child will remain visible, regardless of the parent's visibility setting.

In such a case (where parent/child visibility are set by different style rules), the display:none setting on the parent ***will*** hide all the children--even if parent/children are styled independently.*emphasized text*

Comment: this happened in my last project . use of .css( display none ) then .css(display block) merged to header in table then use .css( visibility hidden ) then .css(visiblity visible)

Answer (score 1):

display: none means that the element is not displayed at all (so you won't see it in the example either).

display: block means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Display None: it hides the control. by setting the property of element style="display:none" element will not rendered in webpage and not take place

Display Block: Show the element on web page in block level

Answer (score 0):

Display none will hide the contains, here if you apply it on div then width and height of div will also hide. 
Display block will show the contains.